# Unable to retrieve data from PG DB (in Azure) using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, sequelize.js

I am unable to retrieve data from a PG DB resource hosted in Azure. I am using Sequelize and Node.

I am able to connect to the DB hosted in Azure using the terminal and a GUI, I can create a new DB with a table and some prepopulated fields to do a proof of concept.

However, when I try to connect in my local and get the data, I get an empty array response ([ ]). If I hit the same endpoint in production, I get a 502 (after a while) with the following message displayed on the client:

Server Error.
There was an unexpected error in the request processing.

Some code below (it works with my local db configured the same way):

This is my DB config:

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var cfg = require('../config');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(cfg.db, cfg.username, cfg.password, {
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },

  host: cfg.host,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  port: 5432
});
```

And this is my router code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var User = require('../../models/users-model');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  User.findAll().then(user => {  
    res.json(user);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Both in local and prod I expect to get the JSON response with an array of User objects.

In my local, as explained, I get an empty array.
In production, as mentioned as well, it seems to timeout and finally I get a 502 err response.

Any help is much appreciated!

**Update!: I managed to activate the app logs on Azure (it took me a bit to find it as I'm quite new to the platform!) and got this now when I hit the endpoint in prod:**

```
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355595892Z Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355632393Z     at connection.connect.err (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:170:24)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355637793Z     at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:191:14)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355641493Z     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355645293Z     at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355648693Z     at Socket.reportStreamError (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:72:10)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355652093Z     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355655393Z     at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355658393Z     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355661493Z     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
2019-08-12T12:52:06.355664693Z     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours, I have hardcoded the data rather than getting that dynamically from my config files, probably I did not set up my Dockerfile properly and was not setting the ENV variable correctly.

Now I attacked the PROD DB from my local and it seems to work! Would really appreciate if someone can affirm my problem lies at the configuration level and the NODE_ENV env node var.

Dockerfile

```
# Node server serving Angular App
FROM node:8.11-alpine as node-server
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY /server /usr/src/app/server
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server
ENV NODE_ENV=prod
RUN npm install --production --silent
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Then in /config/index.js I have:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'global'
  , cfg = require('./config.' + env);

module.exports = cfg;
```

So I understand that by setting the NODE_ENV to prod in Docker, when starting the Node app in Azure it should get the config.prod.js file rather than the config.global.js file, right?

You can see how I implement this on the db.js file on the question.